# Does this neon indicator light require a resistor to limit current?

Tags: resistors, current-limiting, indicator, neon

I've got a few of these indicator lights from LEECRAFT/VCC, they're marked "tineon 3600" and "125V 1/3W". According to this page: http://wiki.diyfaq.org.uk/index.php/Neon neon lamps require a resistor to limit current, but many indicators have them built in. I believe this is the datasheet for the indicators I have: https://vcclite.com/wp-content/uploads/wpallimport/files/files/36and36LSeries.pdf, specifically 36EN-2313, but it doesn't discuss any integrated resistor. Anyone have experience with these and can tell definitively if a resistor in still need or can be used off mains power(117V) as is?

Answer (score 3):

Since these neon indicator lamps are described as operating from 125 or 250 Volts, depending on model, they will include the necesssary resistor, and can be connected directly to the specified voltage.

Likewise, the LED versions will include the necessary current limiting to allow them to be operated from the listed voltage, with no external components.

You only need a current-limiting resistor with a "bare" neon lamp or LED.

Comment: The lack of a spec for a required external resistor is an excellent indication that none is needed.

Comment: Thanks Peter, appreciate the response. 
@WhatRoughBeast agreed, but an indication is sometimes evidence, rarely proof, which is what I came here for :)

Comment: @JoeC. - Given the scanty nature of the data sheet you linked, proof is simply not possible. I agree with Peter's argument and conclusion, but it is not without uncertainty. Companies have been known to do some very strange things with their data sheets, and I have the memories (but fortunately no scars) to prove it.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: in my experience, assemblies such as shown in the linked datasheet are always intended to be operated from the speified voltage, with no extra components.

Comment: @PeterBennett - Mine, too. But assuming that it's always true is...problematic, and I've had cases where similar judgements were wrong, to my sorrow. As the saying goes, "When you  assume..."

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast and Peter, I can confirm this particular part will run off mains power directly without any additional components.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an oscilloscope, and maybe an isolation transformer?  If you hook one of those lamps up with a series resistor it'll just be dim, and the voltage across the lamp itself will rise to the trigger voltage, then flat-top at the run voltage.  If it has a built-in series resistor and you look at the lamp voltage with an O-scope, you'll see a distinctly curvy top & bottom to the wave, if it doesn't, you'll see the initial spike and then a distinctly flat top & bottom.

Comment: Thanks Tim, unfortunately I don't have a scope. It does seem according to another poster here that the resistor is included.

Comment: I was almost gave that as an answer, but I wasn't quite sure, so I gave you the test instead (I would have just plugged one into the wall and seen what happens -- no smoke = joy, and all that).

Comment: Good news, this particular part will run off mains power without any additional components